# Smallest Positive Number - Python - Codility

Tags: python, codelite

I am using Codelite to train myself as I just started learning Python. In the excercise "Smallest Positive Number", I used the code below and some test cases passed, but most of them not. How can I improve my code? (test cases like [1,2,3,4] and repetitive numbers like [5,6,2,4,6].

```
A = [2,1,-2,5,-6]

m = max(A)
temp = []
index = []
result = []

if m < 1:
    print ("1")
elif len(A) == 1:
    if A[0] == 1:
        print("2")
    else:
        print("1")
else:
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] > 0:
            temp.append(A[i])
            temp.sort()
    print(temp)
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        index.append(j+1)
        if temp[j] != index[j]:
            result.append(index[j])

    print(min(result))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if there is only one number on the list and it equals, say, 10? Overall, you code is very un-pythonic. What you want is `print(min(x for x in A if x > 0))`. In other words, maximal use of built-in functions and list comprehensions.

Comment: if this code is about finding smallest number, means to test you data structure part. you don't have to use built-in functions. try writing the min function by yourself

Answer (score 0):

First you would want to store the smallest positive number. Start it at the first element of the list.

```
small_positive = A[0]
```

You would then want to iterate through the input

```
    for number in A:
```

Then check if the number is positive. The easiest way is to see if it is greater then zero.

```
        if number > 0:
```

After, check if the number is smaller then the current smallest. If so, overwrite it.

```
            if number < small_positive:
                small_positive = number
```

Lastly, you need to check if there were all negatives in the list. If small_positive is negative after the loop, there were no positives in the list.

```
if small_positive < 0:
    return None
```

This is the easiest way to understand the solution, but there are many built in functions which are much simpler then this.

Comment: You should try that with the list `[-1, -2, -3]` :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what the return has to be if there are no positives for Codility.

Comment: In Python, it would almost certainly be `None`.

Comment: Jsoulier, that's better.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, this wouldn't work for the list `[-42]`:

```py
m = max(A)
if m < 1:
    print ("1")
```

There's *no* `1` anywhere in that given list so it should not be reported as the solution. Python would usually give you `None` in that scenario but the puzzle you've been set may have other ideas. It also wouldn't work with the list `[]` as `max()` will complain bitterly about the empty list.

You may *think* that one or both of those cases are unlikely but that's one of the things that makes the difference between a good coder and a not-so-good one. The former assume their users and testers are psychotic geniuses who know how to break code with near-zero effort :-)

---

To code it up by yourself, you can use the following pseudo-code<sup>(1)</sup> as a basis:

```py
num_list = (some list of numbers)
min_pos = nothing
for num in num_list:
    if num > 0 and (min_pos is nothing or num < min_pos): # >= ?
        min_pos = num

print(min_pos)
```

Of course, if you're learning *Python* rather than learning *programming,* you should probably just use the facilities of the language, things will be much easier:

```
pos_list = [item for item in the_list if item > 0] # >= ?
min_pos = min(pos_list) if len(pos_list) > 0 else None
print(min_pos)
```

And, if you consider zero to be positive, make sure you use `>= 0` instead of `> 0`, in both code blocks above where indicated.

Both of these snippets will successfully handle lists with no positive numbers, giving you a sentinel value (Python `None` or pseudo-code `nothing`).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Yes, it *looks* a bit like Python but that's only because Python is the ultimate pseudo-code language :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [2,-2,5,-6]



def small(a,b):
    if a >= b: return b
    else: return a




positive_list = [ele for ele in A if ele > 0]
res = min(positive_list)


if len(positive_list) == 0:
    print("no positive number.")
else:
    for i in range(len(positive_list)):
        res = small(res, positive_list[i])

print(f"Smallest Positive number : {res}")
```

by this, yon can easily get a result.